# Combining events in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I was wondering if there is any way to combine events in VB.net. I am using a windows form and have three events for each button that does a different action. I would like to put all three events in one method but am having trouble doing this. Below is an example of one of the buttons. For the ease of the question I removed all the code inside each sub.

```
Private Sub btnRightPos_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnRightPos.Click

End Sub

Private Sub btnRightPos_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRightPos.MouseDown

End Sub

Private Sub btnRightPos_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRightPos.MouseUp

End Sub
```

Comment: If each event does a different action why put them together and then try and figure out which is which?

Comment: If I can put all three events in one method it simplifies the code and makes it easier to read rather then haveing multiple methods in different locations in the code possibly (It is how the code was before it was given to me and I rearranged everything). It is easy to tell which is event is which if I could just find a way to reference each event to a local variable in the method and use a case structure to execute the proper code. This is the issue I am having and wanted to know if there was a way to reference the event in some way.

Answer (score 4):

`MouseUp` and `MouseDown` can be combined by saying  `Handles btnRightPos.MouseDown,  btnRightPos.MouseUp` like this.

```
Private Sub btnRightPos_MouseDownAndDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRightPos.MouseDown,  btnRightPos.MouseUp

End Sub
```

but Button.Click cannot be combined with the other two as it's event handler has a different signature.

On thing you can do to reuse code is to seperate out the common logic into a separate function and just call that function from your event handlers.

Comment: It **can** be combined, if you don't care about the parameters. See my answer. VB.NET lets you use a parameter-less method to say "I don't care about the signature. Figure it out for me".

Comment: @vcsjones I did not know that but I would think atleast the `sender` parameter would be required in most cases to do anything sensible when you have a single handler for multiple events.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. Do you care about the arguments? Do you need `sender` and `e`? You can combine two of them, and if you don't care about the arguments, you can combine all three. The reason being the signature for Click is different. Since Up and Down share the same signature, they could be combined like this:

```
Private Sub btnRightPos_UpAndDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles btnRightPos.MouseDown,  btnRightPos.MouseUp

End Sub
```

If want to combine all three:

```
Private Sub btnRightPos_All() Handles btnRightPos.Click, btnRightPos.MouseUp, btnRightPos.MouseDown

End Sub
```

VB.NET has an interesting feature that lets that work, where you can use a parameter-less method to handle any event; effectively saying "I don't care about the signature, make it work".

Comment: I do not care about the argumants. I understand how you declare the sub but how do I distinguish each event inside the sub since I cant use the event in a case or if stamenent.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this using

```
AddHandler obj.OnEvent, AddressOf MyEventHandler
```

So for example

```
private Default_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
```

and then

```
 AddHandler btnRightPos.MouseUp, AddressOf Default_MouseUp
 AddHandler btnLeftPos.MouseUp, AddressOf Default_MouseUp
```

Answer (score -2):

This seems to be the prudent approach.  If there is something just a little different in one it is easier to fix.  Just because they are identical today...

```
Private Sub btnRightPos_Click(sender As Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                          Handles btnRightPos.Click
    btnRightPosCommon(sender, e, "C")
End Sub

Private Sub btnRightPos_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                  ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                              Handles btnRightPos.MouseDown
    btnRightPosCommon(sender, e, "D")
End Sub

Private Sub btnRightPos_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
                            Handles btnRightPos.MouseUp
    btnRightPosCommon(sender, e, "U")
End Sub

'common
Private Sub btnRightPosCommon(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                              ByVal e As System.Object, Optional id As String = "")

    Debug.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", sender.GetType, e.GetType, id)
End Sub
```

Comment: It is polite, when down voting, to post a comment.

Comment: While it looks like this would work no problem it defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do in the code by eliminating the three event statements into a single event statement. This makes the code longer rather then reducing it.

Comment: You have already said, "I do not care about the argumants. I understand how you declare the sub but how do I distinguish each event inside the sub..."  So if you could do what you wanted it sounds like the sub is going to consist of if then - elseif then statements.  So yes, you might save a line of code or two, but what happens when the next person comes along, looking for the code for the Click event?  What happens if the person double clicks the button on the form and adds code for the resulting "New" event handler?  Maybe you'll down-vote me again, but you aren't making things better.